# Google Cloud Messaging 3rd party server gets "Missing Registration" error on sending message

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to send a message from 3rd-party server. When I send http request using curl command on shell, it works, but when I do the same thing with Ruby script, I keep on getting "Missing Registration" error. More specifically, when I type

```
curl --header "Authorization: key=MY_KEY" --header Content-Type:"application/json" https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send  -d "{\"registration_ids\":[\"MY_REGISTRATION_KEY\"], \"data\":{\"data1\":\"data1val\"}}"
```

I get the following response

{"multicast_id":5609541310450656515,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1346184864739450%3083a1e3f9fd7ecd"}]}
, and the message is correctly received by Android device.

However, if I use the following script, the response from GCM server send error message like "Error=MissingRegistration". (using ruby version 1.9.3)

```
require "net/https"                                                                                                                                                           
require "uri"

uri = URI.parse("https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send")
https = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, 443)
https.use_ssl = true
https.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

https.start{|https|
  request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.path)
  request["Authorization"] = "key=MY_KEY"
  request["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
  request.set_form_data({:registration_ids => ["MY_REGISTRATION_KEY"],
                     :data => {data1:"data1_val"}
                    })
  response = https.request(request)
  p response.body
  p response.header
}
```

I'm feeling like there is some problem around char encoding. I defined charset in content-type header and tried, but the result was same.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 4):

It's about encoding. You have to set request's encoding to UTF8.

Comment: How exactly? Is it a HTTP header? Also how come I don't have to do that when using curl?

Comment: Never mind; it was a bug in the HTTP library was using. Although I'm still not setting the request as UTF-8, and it works (unless the library does it implicitly; `curl` automatically adds `; charset=utf-8` to the `Content-type` header). I'm using cpp-netlib fwiw.

Comment: This solved it for me using libcurl from Ruby; setting `headers['Content-type'] = 'application/json; charset=UTF=8'` fixed this right up.